# Openpyxl remove row group

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to remove **row groups** from an excel file using Openpyxl.
What I already figured out: there is an option to *create* a row group, but I can't find an option to ***remove*** those.
Is this not supported and if not: is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Removing row groups is just like creating them, but you need to select level zero using `"outline_level=0"`. Below you find a code example to remove groups in the entire sheet:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.row_dimensions.group(1, ws.max_row + 1, outline_level=0) # for entire sheet
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The general command is based around using **delete_rows**. Normally specifying, the **active worksheet**, the **delete command** and **specifying the row range** (starting row, ending row).

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.delete_rows(firstrow, numberofrows) #for multiple row deletion
ws.delete_rows(1, ws.max_row+1) # for entire sheet
ws.delete_rows(rownum) #for single row
```

Comment: Thanks - but that is not what I was searching for :-).
I want to REMOVE groups but not to delete all the data, which is included.